# Extjs - Best way to show a tree in a window

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Here's my tree panel that I'm using:

```
var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
                store: mystore,
                rootVisible: false,
                useArrows: true,
                frame: true,
                title: 'Organization Tree',
                renderTo: 'org-filter-window',
                width: 600,
                height: 400,
                dockedItems: [{
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    items: [{
                        text: 'Expand All',
                        handler: function () {
                            tree.expandAll();
                        }
                    }, {
                        text: 'Collapse All',
                        handler: function () {
                            tree.collapseAll();
                        }
                    }]
                }]
            });
```

and I have this window

```
  var orgWindow = Ext.create("Ext.Window", {
        store: myStoe,
        title: 'Organization Tree',
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        html: '<div id="org-filter-window"></div>'
    });
```

Not sure what the best way is to show a tree inside of a window.  As you can see, I've tried rendering the tree panel inside the window html, and it works okay, but I'm not sure if this is the preferred way.

Version: Ext JS 4.0.7

Comment: Would also suggest you read the docs, it explicitly tells you not to do this: "Do not use this option if the Component is to be a child item of a Container. It is the responsibility of the Container's layout manager to render and manage its child items."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
var orgWindow = Ext.create("Ext.Window", {
        store: myStoe,
        title: 'Organization Tree',
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        items: tree // <--- the only change is here
    });
```

and remove `renderTo: 'org-filter-window',` from the `tree` definition